Pasar datos a tabla en Wizar Step de filamentPHP
Necesito pasar información de un componente livewire a una vista livewire y esta vista cargarla en un paso de un resource filament donde utilizo wizard/step, el problema es que no logro resolver el problema y cada vez que ingreso a la ruta me dice que la variable $medidores esta indefinida, la verdad no entiendo bien el por que...
tengo mi componente livewire de esta forma:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\Company\GaugeConsumption;
use Filament\Facades\Filament;

class GaugesTable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        $tenant = Filament::getTenant();
        $medidores = GaugeConsumption::where('company_id', $tenant->id)->paginate(10);

        return view('livewire.gauges-table', [
            'medidores' => $medidores,
        ]);
    }
}

luego tengo mi vista de esta forma
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <table class="w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
                <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                            N° del Medidor
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Nombre del Medidor
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Lectura Anterior
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
                            Lectura Actual
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="bg-gray-800 divide-y divide-gray-200">
                <tbody class="bg-gray-800 divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    @foreach ($medidores as $medidor)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-gray-500">
                            {{ $medidor->gauge_id }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-gray-500">
                            {{ $medidor->month }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-gray-500">
                            {{ $medidor->previousreading }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-gray-500">
                            {{ $medidor->currentreading }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="mt-4">
                {{ $medidores->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

y por ultimo tengo mi resource asi
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Company\Resources;

use App\Filament\Company\Resources\CalculateExpenseResource\Pages;
use App\Filament\Company\Resources\CalculateExpenseResource\RelationManagers;
use App\Models\Company\CalculateExpense;
use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

class CalculateExpenseResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = CalculateExpense::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-c-calculator';

    protected static ?string $tenantOwnershipRelationshipName = 'companies';

    protected static ?int $navigationSort = 60;

    public static function getLabel(): ?string
    {
        return ("Calcular gasto");
    }

    public static function getPluralLabel(): ?string
    {
        return ("Calcular gasto");
    }

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Wizard::make([
                    Forms\Components\Wizard\Step::make('Seleccionar Mes de cobro')
                        ->schema([
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('mescobro')->type('month')
                                ->label('Mes en que se cobrara')
                                ->required()
                                ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $set) {
                                    $set('mescobro', $state);
                                }),
                            Forms\Components\DatePicker::make('vencimiento')
                                ->label('Seleccione una fecha de vencimiento')
                                ->required(),
                        ])
                        ->columns(2),
                    Forms\Components\Wizard\Step::make('Seleccionar Medidores')
                        ->schema([
                            \Filament\Forms\Components\Placeholder::make('gauges_table')
                                ->content(function () {
                                    return view('livewire.gauges-table');
                                })
                        ]),     
                    Forms\Components\Wizard\Step::make('Ingresos')
                        ->schema([]),                  
                ])
                    ->columnSpanFull()
            ]);
    }    
}

y todo eso lleva a que me arroje este error!

La razon de el por que hago esto es basicamente porque dentro de varios de los step necesito cargar unas tablas con registros de un mes en particular que selecciono en el paso 1, pero en filamentphp no he encontrado algo que me permita hacer esto, y la alternativa que estoy trabajando es usar livewire para esto, probe con algunas alternativas de chatgpt pero no me sirvieron y termino dandome ese error de variable indefinida...
Espero que me haya explicado bien en el problema y la necesidad que tengo, si no es asi puedo actualizar la información...
